# javascript creating object to store data and list information

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a ‘customer’ object that will store all of this data and then display the information as a ‘Customer Order’ with listing all the new information.
When I click on the button it doesn't show the output. The output appears for a second and disappear. 
I'm guessing there is a problem in my object array, but not sure.

This is what I have for my javascript.

```js
/*index.js*/

 var objectarray = [];
 var button = document.getElementById("clickMe");

    function addToArray() {
    var customerobject = {};
      customerobject.name = document.getElementById("nameid").value;
      customerobject.address = document.getElementById("addressid").value;
      customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phoneid").value;
      objectarray.push(customerobject);
      console.log(objectarray);
       
    }
   button.addEventListener("click", addToArray);
 


function clicked()

{
//code to get an output from the customer (ordered menu information) 
   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>City Delicatssen</title>
<link href="PartA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="PartA.js">

</script>


</head>



<body>
<!--this is for date-->

<h1>Today is :  <span id="datefield" ></span></h1>

<br>

<br>
<div id="background">
<br>
<h1>Welcome to City Delicatessen </h1>
<div id="contents">

<table cellpadding="5" class="formtable">

<br>
<form name="information">
<table>
<tr><td>  First and Last Name :</td><td><input type="name" id="nameid" size="25" maxlength="25" autofocus="yes" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+$"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Address :</td><td><input type="address" id="addressid" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|,|.|\|@|#|$|%|&)+"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number :</td><td><input type="tel" size="25" id="phoneid" placeholder="XXX XXX XXXX" pattern="\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}"></td></tr>
</form>


<br>
<br>
<form name=order>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr valign=top>
<td>

<h3>Choose Type of Pizza</h3>
<img src="cheesepizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Super Cheesy"checked>Super Cheesy<br>
 <img src="meatpizza.jpg" alt="Forest"> 

<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Extra Meaty">Extra Meaty<br>
 <img src="veggypizza.jpg" alt="Forest"> 

<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Really Veggy">Really Veggy<br>
</td>

<tr>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Size of Pizza</h3>
<input type=radio name=specialty value="Small:8.50" checked>Small<br>

<input type=radio name=specialty value="Medium:11.50">Medium<br>

<input type=radio name=specialty value="Large:14.00">Large<br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value="Extra Large:16.50">Extra Large<br>
</div>
</td>
<br>
<table>
<td>

<h3>Choose Type of Soda</h3>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Cola" checked>Cola<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Orange">Orange<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Lemon">Lemon<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Root Beer">Root Beer<br>
</table>

</td>

</tr>
 
<table style="width:100%">
<tr valign=top>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Type of Sandwich</h3>
<img src="garden.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="All Garden Vegetarian:7.50" checked>All Garden Vegetarian<br>

<img src="beef.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Big Beef on a Bun:8.50">Big Beef on a Bun<br>

<img src="mixedgrill.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Mixed Grill:9.50">Mixed Grill<br>
<img src="grilledpork.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Grilled Pork:9.5">Grilled Pork<br>
</td>
</table>


<td></td>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Size of Soda</h3>
<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Small:1.25" checked>Small<br>

<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Medium:1.75">Medium<br>

<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Large:2.00">Large<br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Choose Toppings</h3>
<input type=checkbox name=extracheese checked value=1.75>Extra Cheese<br>

<input type=checkbox name=pepperoni value=1.75>Pepperoni<br>

<input type=checkbox name=mushroom value=1.75>Mushroom<br>

<input type=checkbox name=bacon value=1.75>Bacon<br>
<input type=checkbox name=olives value=1.75>Olives<br>
</td>
</div>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br>Quantity of Pizza<input type="number" size="3" id="quantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
<td><br>Quantity of Sandwich<input type="number" size="3" id="sandwichquantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
<td><br>Quantity of Drink<input type="number" size="3" id="sodaquantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<center><button id="clickMe" value="Price your Order" onClick="clicked()">click me</button></center>

</form>

  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html eve?

Comment: @Rai Yeah, I added my html :)

Comment: It's just a tiny problem Eve. The form is submitting itself when you click the button, hence it's refreshing the page. You just need to specify the `type` of the button. Also, there are a few mistakes in the closing tags of various elements. Refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292835/10232790) to fix those glitches. As for the primary problem, all other answers too are right.

Comment: @Rai thank you so much! It works! I do really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Eve, all you need to is **add `type="button"` to the `button` tag**.

This is because button elements are, by default, `type="submit"`. Because it is a form that you are using, and the button is in the form, on clicking that button, it plainly submits it. Since the form has no explicit action attribute, it submits itself to the current page URL, refreshing the page.

> A button without specified type submits the form as a default action.

- Hence the only change you need to make to make this work is add `type = "button"` to the button tag.
- And if you need to show this `customerobject` object in the html page, just create a `div` assign the value of the object using `innerHTML`.

  Also, Just as a bonus: Your closing tags are not quite right. I have fixed them and updated below.

```js
/*index.js*/

var objectarray = [];
var button = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var customerobject = {};

function addToArray() {
  customerobject.name = document.getElementById("nameid").value;
  customerobject.address = document.getElementById("addressid").value;
  customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phoneid").value;
  objectarray.push(customerobject);
  console.log(objectarray);
  document.getElementById("orderInfo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(customerobject);
}



function clicked()

{
  //code to get an output from the customer (ordered menu information) 



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>City Delicatssen</title>
  <link href="PartA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="PartA.js">
  </script>


</head>



<body>
  <!--this is for date-->

  <h1>Today is : <span id="datefield"></span></h1>

  <br>

  <br>
  <div id="background">
    <br>
    <h1>Welcome to City Delicatessen </h1>
    <div id="contents">

      <table cellpadding="5" class="formtable">

        <br>
        <form name="information">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td> First and Last Name :</td>
              <td><input type="name" id="nameid" size="25" maxlength="25" autofocus="yes" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+$"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> Address :</td>
              <td><input type="address" id="addressid" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|,|.|\|@|#|$|%|&)+"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Phone Number :</td>
              <td><input type="tel" size="25" id="phoneid" placeholder="XXX XXX XXXX" pattern="\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>


        <br>
        <br>
        <form name=order>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr valign=top>
              <td>

                <h3>Choose Type of Pizza</h3>
                <img src="cheesepizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Super Cheesy" checked>Super Cheesy<br>
                <img src="meatpizza.jpg" alt="Forest">

                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Extra Meaty">Extra Meaty<br>
                <img src="veggypizza.jpg" alt="Forest">

                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Really Veggy">Really Veggy<br>
              </td>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="border_div">
                    <h3>Choose Size of Pizza</h3>
                    <input type=radio name=specialty value="Small:8.50" checked>Small<br>

                    <input type=radio name=specialty value="Medium:11.50">Medium<br>

                    <input type=radio name=specialty value="Large:14.00">Large<br>
                    <input type=radio name=specialty value="Extra Large:16.50">Extra Large<br>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <br>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>

                      <h3>Choose Type of Soda</h3>
                      <input type=radio name=sodatype value="Cola" checked>Cola<br>
                      <input type=radio name=sodatype value="Orange">Orange<br>
                      <input type=radio name=sodatype value="Lemon">Lemon<br>
                      <input type=radio name=sodatype value="Root Beer">Root Beer<br>


                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table style="width:100%">
                  <tr valign=top>
                    <td>
                      <div id="border_div">
                        <h3>Choose Type of Sandwich</h3>
                        <img src="garden.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="All Garden Vegetarian:7.50" checked>All Garden Vegetarian<br>

                        <img src="beef.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Big Beef on a Bun:8.50">Big Beef on a Bun<br>

                        <img src="mixedgrill.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Mixed Grill:9.50">Mixed Grill<br>
                        <img src="grilledpork.jpg" alt="">
                        <input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Grilled Pork:9.5">Grilled Pork<br>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>


                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <div id="border_div">
                    <h3>Choose Size of Soda</h3>
                    <input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Small:1.25" checked>Small<br>

                    <input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Medium:1.75">Medium<br>

                    <input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Large:2.00">Large<br>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <h3>Choose Toppings</h3>
                  <input type=checkbox name=extracheese checked value=1.75>Extra Cheese<br>

                  <input type=checkbox name=pepperoni value=1.75>Pepperoni<br>

                  <input type=checkbox name=mushroom value=1.75>Mushroom<br>

                  <input type=checkbox name=bacon value=1.75>Bacon<br>
                  <input type=checkbox name=olives value=1.75>Olives<br>
                </td>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><br>Quantity of Pizza<input type="number" size="3" id="quantity" min="0"></td>
                <br>
                <td><br>Quantity of Sandwich<input type="number" size="3" id="sandwichquantity" min="0"></td>
                <br>
                <td><br>Quantity of Drink<input type="number" size="3" id="sodaquantity" min="0"></td>
                <br>
              </tr>
          </table>


          <center><button type="button" id="clickMe" value="Price your Order" onClick="addToArray()">click me</button></center>

        </form>
        
        <!-- Add the below div section to print the details on your webpage-->
        <div id="orderInfo">

        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, when you submit a form, it will refresh the page. You need to prevent the default action when a form is submitted by using the .preventDefault() function. Will update your code below to demonstrate and add a couple comments.

```js
/*index.js*/

 var objectarray = [];
 var button = document.getElementById("clickMe");

    // add the event to the function
   button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault(); // Add this line
      var customerobject = {};
      customerobject.name = document.getElementById("nameid").value;
      customerobject.address = document.getElementById("addressid").value;
      customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phoneid").value;
      objectarray.push(customerobject);
      console.log(objectarray);
   });
 


function clicked()

{
//code to get an output from the customer (ordered menu information) 
   

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>City Delicatssen</title>
<link href="PartA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="PartA.js">

</script>


</head>



<body>
<!--this is for date-->

<h1>Today is :  <span id="datefield" ></span></h1>

<br>

<br>
<div id="background">
<br>
<h1>Welcome to City Delicatessen </h1>
<div id="contents">

<table cellpadding="5" class="formtable">

<br>
<form name="information">
<table>
<tr><td>  First and Last Name :</td><td><input type="name" id="nameid" size="25" maxlength="25" autofocus="yes" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+$"></td></tr>
<tr><td> Address :</td><td><input type="address" id="addressid" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|,|.|\|@|#|$|%|&)+"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number :</td><td><input type="tel" size="25" id="phoneid" placeholder="XXX XXX XXXX" pattern="\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}"></td></tr>
</form>


<br>
<br>
<form name=order>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr valign=top>
<td>

<h3>Choose Type of Pizza</h3>
<img src="cheesepizza.jpg" alt="Forest">
<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Super Cheesy"checked>Super Cheesy<br>
 <img src="meatpizza.jpg" alt="Forest"> 

<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Extra Meaty">Extra Meaty<br>
 <img src="veggypizza.jpg" alt="Forest"> 

<input type=radio name=pizzatype value="Really Veggy">Really Veggy<br>
</td>

<tr>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Size of Pizza</h3>
<input type=radio name=specialty value="Small:8.50" checked>Small<br>

<input type=radio name=specialty value="Medium:11.50">Medium<br>

<input type=radio name=specialty value="Large:14.00">Large<br>
<input type=radio name=specialty value="Extra Large:16.50">Extra Large<br>
</div>
</td>
<br>
<table>
<td>

<h3>Choose Type of Soda</h3>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Cola" checked>Cola<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Orange">Orange<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Lemon">Lemon<br>
<input type=radio name=sodatype value="Root Beer">Root Beer<br>
</table>

</td>

</tr>
 
<table style="width:100%">
<tr valign=top>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Type of Sandwich</h3>
<img src="garden.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="All Garden Vegetarian:7.50" checked>All Garden Vegetarian<br>

<img src="beef.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Big Beef on a Bun:8.50">Big Beef on a Bun<br>

<img src="mixedgrill.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Mixed Grill:9.50">Mixed Grill<br>
<img src="grilledpork.jpg" alt="">
<input type=radio name=sandwichtype value="Grilled Pork:9.5">Grilled Pork<br>
</td>
</table>


<td></td>
<td><div id="border_div">
<h3>Choose Size of Soda</h3>
<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Small:1.25" checked>Small<br>

<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Medium:1.75">Medium<br>

<input type=radio name=sodaspecialty value="Large:2.00">Large<br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Choose Toppings</h3>
<input type=checkbox name=extracheese checked value=1.75>Extra Cheese<br>

<input type=checkbox name=pepperoni value=1.75>Pepperoni<br>

<input type=checkbox name=mushroom value=1.75>Mushroom<br>

<input type=checkbox name=bacon value=1.75>Bacon<br>
<input type=checkbox name=olives value=1.75>Olives<br>
</td>
</div>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br>Quantity of Pizza<input type="number" size="3" id="quantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
<td><br>Quantity of Sandwich<input type="number" size="3" id="sandwichquantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
<td><br>Quantity of Drink<input type="number" size="3" id="sodaquantity" min="0"></td>
<br>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<center><button id="clickMe" value="Price your Order" onClick="clicked()">click me</button></center>

</form>

  
</body>

</html>
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: happy to help.  Please mark the answer as correct if happy with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your clickMe button add

> type="button"

attribute:

```html
<center><button id="clickMe" type="button" value="Price your Order" onClick = "clicked()">click me</button></center>
```